# Reminder email need to send to the users

Tags: apex, unit-test

I need to send the Reminder e-mail to the below user & all the below users belongs to the same PROFILE (Test1) : 2 pm UK time on Thursday of every week.

User1 – UK – time zone BST (GMT + 1)

User2 – Switzerland – CEST (GMT + 2)

User3 – Belgium - CEST (GMT + 2)

User4 – Spain - CEST (GMT + 2)

**Batch Class**

```
global class SendEmail1 Implements Schedulable
{
   global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
                sendmail();
    }

    public void sendmail(){
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        List<User> userList = [select id,email,profile.name from user where profile.name= 'Test1'];
        string [] toAddress= new string[]{};
        for(User u:userList){
            toAddress.add(u.email);
        }                                   
        email.setSubject('SUBJECT  ABC XYZ');
        email.setPlainTextBody('Update Your Data Into The Salesforce');
        email.setToAddresses(toAddress);
        Messaging.sendEmail(New Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{email});
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@IsTest
 public with sharing class Test_SendEmailTest {
    static testmethod void testSample(){
        Test.startTest();
        Datetime dt = Datetime.now().addMinutes(1);
        String CRON_EXP = '0 '+ dt.minute() + ' * ' + dt.day() + ' ' + dt.month() + ' ? ' + dt.year();
        String jobId = System.schedule('Sample_Heading', CRON_EXP, new SendEmail1() );   
        Test.stopTest();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: i want to send the email notification to all the above user at the same time. @2 pm UK time on Thursday of every week. once i will apply my code into the Scheduled Jobs it will fire only in IST format. but i want to send @2.00PM UK time